# converting xml document to byte array in Java

Tags: java, xml, base64, arrays

I am trying to convert an arbitrary Xml Document to a byte array so that it can be encoded using Base64. Can anybody help me with how to go about this. Also, what's the easiest api to use for base64 encoding in Java?

Thanks.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have you looked at any documentation yet? Show us some code for things you have tried.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest API for base64 encoding is probably [Commons Codec](http://commons.apache.org/codec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/binary/Base64.html#encodeBase64String%28byte%5b%5d%29).

Comment: using the api it is done something like this:
byte[] encode = Base64.encode(unencodedString.getBytes());
String encodedString = new String(encode);

Comment: This is only an answer because of @SeanF. Normally I would flag this as a comment

Comment: Thanks guys...here's what I came up with. Still doesn't work.

Comment: public static void main(String[] args) {
  
  try{
        File  f = new File("servers.xml");
          
          FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(f);
         byte [] ba = new byte[(int)f.length()];
          fis.read(ba);
   }
   catch (Exception e){
          System.out.println("exception occurred ==>"+e);
      } 
   
   byte [] code = Base64.encodeBase64(ba);

 }